# Error: Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed al intentar crear una Base de Datos

Tags: mysql

-- Esta instrucción crea una nueva base de datos llamada db_matricula

```
CREATE DATABASE db_cinema CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci;
```

-- Esta instrucción establece la base de datos activa actual a db_matricula

```
USE db_cinema;
```

-- Crear la tabla tb_salas

```
CREATE TABLE  tb_salas (
    Id_salas INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    capacidad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id_salas)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish2_ci;
```

-- Crear la tabla tb_directores

```
CREATE TABLE  tb_directores (
    Id_directores INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id_directores)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish2_ci;
```

-- Crear la tabla tb_genero

```
CREATE TABLE  tb_genero (
    Id_genero INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id_genero)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish2_ci;
```

-- Crear la tabla tb_actores

```
CREATE TABLE  tb_actores (
    Id_actores INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id_actores)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish2_ci;
```

-- Crear la tabla tb_reparto

```
CREATE TABLE  tb_reparto (
    Id_reparto INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Id_peliculas INT(5) NOT NULL,
    Nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id_reparto),
    CONSTRAINT FK_reparto_peliculas FOREIGN KEY (Id_peliculas) REFERENCES tb_peliculas (Id_peliculas)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish2_ci;
```

-- Crear la tabla tb_peliculas

```
CREATE TABLE tb_peliculas (
    Id_peliculas INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Id_directores INT(5) NOT NULL,
    Id_genero INT(5) NOT NULL,
    Id_reparto INT(5) NOT NULL,
    titulo VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    idiomas VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    duration VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Id_peliculas),
    CONSTRAINT FK_peliculas_directores FOREIGN KEY (Id_directores) REFERENCES tb_directores (Id_directores),
    CONSTRAINT FK_peliculas_genero FOREIGN KEY (Id_genero) REFERENCES tb_genero (Id_genero),
    CONSTRAINT FK_peliculas_reparto FOREIGN KEY (Id_reparto) REFERENCES tb_reparto (Id_reparto)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish2_ci;

CREATE TABLE tb_cartelera (
    Id_cartelera INT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Id_salas INT(5) NOT NULL,
    Id_peliculas INT(5) NOT NULL,
    Horario VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    restriction_edad VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (Id_cartelera),
    CONSTRAINT FK_cartelera_salas FOREIGN KEY (Id_salas) REFERENCES tb_salas (Id_salas),
    CONSTRAINT FK_peliculas_peliculas FOREIGN KEY (Id_peliculas) REFERENCES tb_peliculas (Id_peliculas)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_spanish2_ci;
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
> #1005 - Can't create table `db_cinema`.`tb_reparto` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: [es.so] no es un servicio de detección de errores/depuración. ¿Qué problema/error estás teniendo? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: [1/2] El error [en la creación] está en que hay un mal diseño en la lógica relacional. Hay una referencia circular entre `tb_reparto` y `tb_peliculas` Una se hace referencia a la otra, así que al intentar crear cualquiera de las 2 tablas, buscará la otra para crear la FK y mostrará mensaje de error. Solución: Corregir la referencia circular. No es ley, pero una forma de darse cuenta de ese problema, es ver igual o más relaciones que cantidad de tablas involucradas.

Comment: [2/2] Por otro lado `tb_peliculas` tiene `Id_directores`, `Id_genero`, `Id_reparto` como índices con FK hacia esas tablas respectivas. ¿Qué crees que pasará cuando intentes crear la primera película? Faltarán esos idx, devolviendo **error**. Debes crear las FK en relación a `Id_peliculas`. Esta BD está **mal diseñada**, debes leer más sobre [modelo relacional](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+modelo+relacional).